# Why has Eclipse Yocto plugin support been abandoned

Tags: eclipse, sdk, eclipse-cdt, yocto

With older versions of Yocto and Eclipse I was able to use the Yocto Eclipse plugin (up to eclipse oxygen there was support from Yocto). However, it seems that development has been abandoned and with latest releases of both tools there seem no support anymore.

*Questions*: Why has it been removed from the Yocto project and what are the alternatives now? Using Eclipse (or another IDE) to develop with my Yocto generated cross-compilation platform is still something I would desire. Am I the only one?

Regards,
Henk

Comment: Better ask this on their mailing list: https://www.yoctoproject.org/community/mailing-lists/

Comment: Have you found a work around for this? I have attempted to setup eclipse to use the Yocto cross compiler.

Answer (score 1):

The eclipse plugin was developered by developers at Intel. Unfortunately they were moved on to new projects and nobody else stepped forward to continue support for the plugin. The Yocto Project reluctantly stopped maintaining them simply because there was nobody to do it.

Sadly a lot of these kinds of developments don't happen for free and have ongoing maintenance requirements. The project struggles in a number of areas to keep these kinds of features alive and well.

Answer (score 0):

As the original answer was given, they dropped the official support for it because nobody was able to support it for everyone.  Like with all FOSS stuff, no people able to work on it means something's left to die.

This can be viewed in several ways.  It wasn't best of breed, it was cost prohibitive to maintain as anything other than a commercial product, and the like.

As for alternatives.  I've managed to use VS Code with a few extensions, including a bitbake supporting one, to do most of my work in either image/package build modes or eSDK modes.  It has ended up being one of the cleaner ways to do the work I've seen there.  Now, if you're using a classic cross-compile SDK, you can still pretty much use your Eclipse and all.  (Have your cake and eat it too...)   You just really need to be in a Linux environment and source out the SDK config before you start Eclipse to gain it's benefits.

It'd be nice if someone could pick it back up as I've a consulting client that uses Eclipse's modeling tool framework as a frontend to a LOT more sophisticated solution  than just an IDE, so it'd be nice to bolt this on through a docker and gracefully run the builds and the eSDK right.  I don't think, though, that the plugin was that sort of affair...so...

Comment: Sigh.  The bot's a joke.  There's no need for "additional supporting information," here.